# What do you do if a genkoyoshi line ends with e.g. す。」?

Tags: handwriting, orthography, genkōyōshi

Suppose that you're writing on genkoyoshi (原稿用紙), and you are writing a quotation, e.g.

> 「これはペンです。」

And let's say that each line of the genkoyoshi has 8 blocks. The first block would, I presume, be occupied by `「`, followed by one block for each of the kana `こ`・`れ`・`は`・`ペ`・`ン`・`で`.

What do you do with the rest of the quotation? My understanding is that you're not supposed to put punctuation at the beginning of a new line, so you can't split it `す` and `。」`, nor `す。` and `」`. Do you just glom all of `す。」` into a single block?

(Or do you just never include a `。` immediately prior to a closing `」`?)

Comment: Cram all three into the bottommost block -- "す。」".  The better schools, teachers and publishers will not accept any other method.

Comment: @非回答者 それ、回答欄へ、どぞ！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [非回答者](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4032/%E9%9D%9E%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E8%80%85)

> Cram all three into the bottommost block -- "す。」". The better schools,
>   teachers and publishers will not accept any other method.

Comment: Made 非回答者's comment into an answer as community wiki