# On 原稿用紙, when are ゛ and ゜ (ten-ten and maru) supposed to occupy a square of their own?

Tags: handwriting, genkōyōshi

I was intrigued by this question: [What do you do if a genkoyoshi line ends with e.g. す。」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17360/what-do-you-do-if-a-genkoyoshi-line-ends-with-e-g-%E3%81%99) and its answer.

I'm not any good at this 原稿用紙 but I remember being told for some types of forms (which I thought followed the same rules) that you need to put the [濁点]{だくてん} (for some reason always called ten-ten and maru in the classes and contexts I heard them) into separate boxes. Was I being misled / is this still current practice for some sort of form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule you mentioned does not apply to 原稿用紙 for novels and articles. Never.

However, you may be instructed to place 濁点（゛） and 半濁点（゜）into a separate box, when you have to fill some legacy paper forms at banks or government offices.

[image]

This is because 濁点 and 半濁点 consume an extra byte if you encode [hankaku katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-width_kana) strings into old encodings such as JIS, Shift-JIS, EUC-JP, and they have to count the number of bytes.

In my opinion, this is a very bad tradition of the fixed-length-string era, and should disappear at once.

Comment: Thanks. I agree they should disappear. It's really annoying to forget and put something in only to realize I've ruined another form.

Comment: Once upon a time in Japan, someone had a **good idea**: “let's denote different but similar sounds with short markings ( ゛& ゜) to modify existing characters and save space.” Sometime later, someone else had a **bad idea** that negated the good one: “Let's require each of the short markings to occupy one *entire* fixed-width block of character space.” Fail. Never mind that Japanese has systems for text conversion (of kana to kanji, for example). So giving a character like ダ its own glyph in a font was already a trivial matter. That this was never implemented for 半角カナ or forms is mind-boggling.

Comment: Got curious enough to actually [read up on it a little](https://curio-shiki.com/blog/diary/hankaku-zenkaku). It turns out half-width kana predates even kanji. It predates Unicode! It's essentially a tech relic established by computer scientists of the late 1960s who had their hands full enough just trying to get *any* Japanese text to display on a screen. As you said, naruto. I couldn't find info on whether there were enough bytes in the table for 半角の「ダ」etc, but even if there were, space was constrained. Maybe someday a 半角カナ variant will be created that is compact but without awkward  ゛& ゜.