# Is wrapping punctuation to a new line ok?

Tags: punctuation

I am adding support for Japanese to a PDF generation tool and I noticed that punctuation is sometimes wrapped to a new line.

I don't know enough about the Japanese language to know if this is okay or not. There are some cases where the only character on the new line is punctuation which looks very out of place.

[image: japanese text showing punctuation starting a new line]

Comment: Typesetting rules for Japanese and more generally for CJK languages can be pretty complex. As for wrapping punctuation, a basic start would be the Wikipedia page [Line breaking rules in East Asian languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_breaking_rules_in_East_Asian_languages): "For example, periods and closing parentheses are not allowed to start a line."

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17360/9831

Comment: Are you using LaTeX? There are good packages for CJK fonts already with sensible defaults.

Comment: If you are on the implementer's side, [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/jlreq/) is I think what you want.